# CPython: Why does += for strings change the id of string variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, python-internals

Cpython optimizes string increment operations,When initializing memory for a string, the program leaves extra expansion space for it,so, when incrementing, the original string is not copied to the new location.
my question is why the id of string variable changes.

```
>>> s = 'ab'
>>> id(s)
991736112104
>>> s += 'cd'
>>> id(s)
991736774080
```

why the id of string variable changes.

Comment: Don't you mean cpython (and not cython)?

Comment: Why do you think, there is an extra space in string available?

Comment: If you do actually mean Cython, then string concatenation is [actually something it does not optimise, and that the CPython interpreter sometimes does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787022/cython-string-concatenation-is-super-slow-what-else-does-it-do-poorly).

Comment: i'm wrong, it's CPython. i see it on the book 'fluent python'

Comment: Because while the *underlying buffer may not change*, the *string object* does. And `id` is the `id` of the *string object*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The optimization you are trying to trigger is an implementation detail of CPython and is a quite subtle thing:  there are many details (e.f. one you are experiencing) which can be preventing it.

For a detailed explanation, one needs to dive into the CPython's implementation, so first I will try to give a hand-waving explanation, which should give at least the gist of what is going on. The gory details will be in the second part which highlights the important code-parts.

---

Let's take a look at this function, which exhibits the desired/optimized behavior

```
def add_str(str1, str2, n):
    for i in range(n):
        str1+=str2
        print(id(str1))
    return str1
```

Calling it, leads to the following output:

```
>>> add_str("1","2",100)
2660336425032
... 4 times
2660336425032
2660336418608
... 6 times
2660336418608
2660336361520
... 6 times
2660336361520
2660336281800
 and so on
```

I.e. a new string is created only every 8 addition, otherwise the old string (or as we will see the memory) is reused. The first id is printed only 6 times because it starts printing when the size of the unicode-object is 2 modulo 8 (and not 0 as in the later cases).

The first question is, if a string is immutable in CPython, how (or better when) can it be changed? Obviously, we can't change the string if it is bound to different variables - but we could change it, if the current variable is the only one reference - which can be checked pretty easily due to reference counting of CPython (and it is the reason why this optimization isn't available for other implementation which don't use reference counting).

Let's change the function above by adding a additional reference:

```
def add_str2(str1, str2, n):
    for i in range(n):
        ref = str1
        str1+=str2
        print(id(str1))
    return str1
```

Calling it leads to:

```
>>> add_str2("1","2",20)
2660336437656
2660337149168
2660337149296
2660337149168
2660337149296
... every time a different string - there is copying!
```

This actually explains your observation:

```
import sys
s = 'ab'
print(sys.getrefcount(s))
# 9
print(id(s))
# 2660273077752
s+='a'
print(id(s))
# 2660337158664  Different
```

Your string `s` is [interned](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern) (see for example [this SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53506425/5769463) for more information about string interning and integer pool), and thus `s` is not only one "using" this string and thus this string cannot be changed.

If we avoid the interning, we can see, that the string is reused:

```
import sys
s = 'ab'*21  # will not be interned
print(sys.getrefcount(s))
# 2, that means really not interned
print(id(s))
# 2660336107312
s+='a'
print(id(s))
# 2660336107312  the same id!
```

But how does this optimization works?

CPython uses its own memory management - [the pymalloc allocator](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html#the-pymalloc-allocator), which is optimized for small objects with short lifetimes. The used memory-blocks are multiple of `8` bytes, that means if allocator is asked for only 1 byte, still 8 bytes are marked as used (more precise because of the [8-byte aligment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/obmalloc.c#L791) of the returned pointers the the remaining 7 bytes cannot be used for other objects).

There is however the function [`PyMem_Realloc`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html#c.PyMem_Realloc): if the allocator is asked to reallocate a 1byte-block as a 2byte-block, there is nothing to do - there were some reserved bytes anyway.

This way, if there is only one reference to the string, CPython can ask the allocator to reallocate the string and require a byte more. In 7 cases of 8 there is nothing to do for allocator and the additional byte becomes available almost free.

However, if the size of the string changes by more than 7 bytes, the copying becomes mandatory:

```
>>> add_str("1", "1"*8, 20)  # size change of 8
2660337148912
2660336695312
2660336517728
... every time another id
```

Furthermore, pymalloc falls back to `PyMem_RawMalloc`, which is usually the memory manager of the C-runtime, and the above optimization for strings is no longer possible:

```
>>> add_str("1"*512, "1", 20) #  str1 is larger as 512 bytes
2660318800256
2660318791040
2660318788736
2660318807744
2660318800256
2660318796224
... every time another id
```

Actually, whether the addresses are different after each reallocation depends on the memory allocator of the C-runtime and its state. If memory isn't defragmented, the chances are high,  that `realloc` manages to extend memory without copying (but it was not the case on my machine as I did these experiments), see also [this SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55065575/5769463).

---

For the curious, here is the whole traceback of the `str1+=str2` operation, which can be easily followed in [a debugger](https://devguide.python.org/gdb/):

That is what going on:

The `+=` is compiled to `BINARY_ADD`-optcode and when evaluated in `ceval.c`, there is a hook/[special handling for unicode objects](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Python/ceval.c#L1287) (see `PyUnicode_CheckExact`):

```
case TARGET(BINARY_ADD): {
    PyObject *right = POP();
    PyObject *left = TOP();
    PyObject *sum;
    ...
    if (PyUnicode_CheckExact(left) &&
             PyUnicode_CheckExact(right)) {
        sum = unicode_concatenate(left, right, f, next_instr);
        /* unicode_concatenate consumed the ref to left */
    }
    ...
```

[`unicode_concatenate`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Python/ceval.c#L5075) ends up calling [`PyUnicode_Append`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11312), which checks whether the left-operand is modifiable (which [basically checks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L1855) that there is only one reference, string isn't interned and some further stuff) and resizes it or creates a new unicode-object otherwise:

```
if (unicode_modifiable(left)
    && ...)
{
    /* append inplace */
    if (unicode_resize(p_left, new_len) != 0)
        goto error;

    /* copy 'right' into the newly allocated area of 'left' */
    _PyUnicode_FastCopyCharacters(*p_left, left_len, right, 0, right_len);
}
else {
    ...
    /* Concat the two Unicode strings */
    res = PyUnicode_New(new_len, maxchar);
    if (res == NULL)
        goto error;
    _PyUnicode_FastCopyCharacters(res, 0, left, 0, left_len);
    _PyUnicode_FastCopyCharacters(res, left_len, right, 0, right_len);
    Py_DECREF(left);
    ...
}
```

[`unicode_resize`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L1874) ends up calling [`resize_compact`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L918) (mostly because in our case we have only ascii-characters), [which ends up](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L954) calling `PyObject_REALLOC`:

```
...
new_unicode = (PyObject *)PyObject_REALLOC(unicode, new_size);
...
```

which basically will be calling [`pymalloc_realloc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/obmalloc.c#L1819):

```
static int
pymalloc_realloc(void *ctx, void **newptr_p, void *p, size_t nbytes)
{
    ...
    /* pymalloc is in charge of this block */
    size = INDEX2SIZE(pool->szidx);
    if (nbytes <= size) {
        /* The block is staying the same or shrinking.
          ....
            *newptr_p = p;
            return 1; // 1 means success!
          ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Where [`INDEX2SIZE`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/obmalloc.c#L802) just rounds up to the nearest multiple of 8:

```
#define ALIGNMENT               8               /* must be 2^N */
#define ALIGNMENT_SHIFT         3

/* Return the number of bytes in size class I, as a uint. */
#define INDEX2SIZE(I) (((uint)(I) + 1) << ALIGNMENT_SHIFT)
```

qed.

Comment: You speak very well. But I have a question: >>> add_str("1","2",100) 2660336425032 ... 4 times 2660336425032 2660336418608 ... 6 times 2660336418608, why is it 4 times instead of 5 times there

Comment: Some people say that `if allocator is asked for only 1 byte, still 8 bytes are marked as used` is wrong, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L1855.   Can you explain what `resize`is?

Comment: @WangTanxu Who says it and where? Because pointers are 8byte alligned https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/obmalloc.c#L791, the remaining bytes cannot be used in other objects.

Answer (score 5):

Strings are immutabale.  Using `+=` on a `str` is not an in-place operation; it creates a new object with a new memory address, which is what `id()` gives under CPython's implementation.

---

For `str` specifically, `__iadd__` is not defined, so the operation falls back to a either `__add__` or `__radd__`.  See the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) section of the Python docs for some detail.

```
>>> hasattr(s, '__iadd__')                                                                                                                                
False
```

Comment: I arrived at the same conclusion by trying simply in python and not in cython. But, why do you think `s='a' id(s+'b') != id('ab')` ?

Comment: I thought `s + 'b'` was modifying the pointer to 'ab', thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Salomon: actually, `id(1) == id(1)` (as well, obviously, as `1 is 1`) is true (due to an implementation detail - cpython caches small integers). `id(1) is id(1)` is _usually_ false because CPython ids are memory addresses expressed as integers, and those integers are (here again _usually_) way greater than what CPython considers as "small enough" to be cached.  Also, strings that _could_ be valid python names are cached too (try  `id("foo") == id("f" + "oo")` for example). As a conclusion: do not rely on identity for immutable types, as they can - or not - be subject to runtime optimisations.

Comment: Under some conditions `+=` is done in place for unicode-strings in CPython. However, because `ab` is interned, those conditions aren't satisfied in the example of OP.