# what OBVIOUS thing am i missing between strings being immutable in python and the following code working? spare me as im very new to python

Tags: python

```
# Function to convert   
def listToString(s):  
    
    # initialize an empty string 
    str1 = ""  
    
    # traverse in the string   
    for ele in s:  
        str1 += ele   
    
    # return string   
    return str1  
        
        
# Driver code     
s = ['Geeks', 'for', 'Geeks'] 
print(listToString(s)
```

Comment: str1 += ele is shorthanf for str1 = str1+ele. Each time a nez string is created and assigned to str1.

Answer (score 0):

It's not mutating the string.

```
str1 += ele
```

is equivalent to

```
str1 = str1 + ele
```

This creates a new string, it doesn't modify the existing string in place. You can see this if you do:

```
str1 = "xxx"
str2 = str1
str1 += "yyy"
print(str1, str2)
```

This will print `xxxyyy xxx`

There is some internal optimization in CPython that will reuse the memory if possible. See [Python string concatenation internal details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063068/python-string-concatenation-internal-details). But this is undetectable because it only takes place when there's one reference to the string. So in the above example, the optimization is prevented because `str1` and `str2` both refer to the original string; a copy of the string will have to be made when concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other posts, `str += ele` creates a new string instead of changing the old one. You can see this by looking at the `id` of the object. I changed your code slightly to clarify:

```
# Function to convert
def listToString(s):
    # initialize an empty string
    str1 = ""

    # traverse in the string
    for i in range(len(s)):
        print("id of str1: {}".format(id(str1)))
        print("id of s: {}".format(id(s)))
        str1 += s[i]
        s[i] = i

    print(s)

    # return string
    return str1
# Driver code
s = ['Geeks', 'for', 'Geeks']
print(listToString(s))
```

which gives as output:

```
id of str1: 140451112373360
id of s: 140451111710920
id of str1: 140451111354016
id of s: 140451111710920
id of str1: 140451110861808
id of s: 140451111710920
[0, 1, 2]
GeeksforGeeks
```

As you can see, the `id` of the list never changes, because it's the same object. On the other hand, the `id` of `str1` does change.