# Can't resize a tuple using ctypes.pythonapi

Tags: python, tuples, ctypes, python-c-api

Only for testing, I tried to resize a tuple using `ctypes`, with terrible results:

```py
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import py_object, c_long, pythonapi
>>> _PyTuple_Resize = pythonapi._PyTuple_Resize
>>> _PyTuple_Resize.argtypes = (py_object, c_long)
>>> a = ()
>>> b = c_long(1)
>>> _PyTuple_Resize(a, b)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What was going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues with your code.

Let's start with the signature of [`_PyTuple_Resize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c._PyTuple_Resize), it is

```c
int _PyTuple_Resize(PyObject **p, Py_ssize_t newsize)
```

i.e. the first arguments isn't a `py_object` (which would be `PyObject *p`), but a `py_object` [passed by reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference), that means:

```py
from ctypes import POINTER, py_object, c_ssize_t, byref, pythonapi
_PyTuple_Resize = pythonapi._PyTuple_Resize
_PyTuple_Resize.argtypes = (POINTER(py_object), c_ssize_t)
```

However, there is no need to define the arguments of `_PyTuple_Resize` (as any [other pythonapi-function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.LibraryLoader.LoadLibrary)), one only has to define `restype` if it is not `int` (but it is in case of `_PyTuple_Resize`).

Then, the above linked documentation states:

> Because tuples are *supposed* to be immutable, this should only be used if there is only one reference to the object. Do not use this if the tuple may already be known to some other part of the code.

Well, the empty tuple is quite known to other parts of the code:

```py
import sys
a=()
sys.getrefcount(a)
# 28236
```

As @CristiFati has pointed out in comments this is a small optimization, which can be done because tuples are immutable: all empty tuples share the same singleton. So using `_PyTuple_Resize` on empty tuple is quite problematic, even if this corner case is caught in the [code of `_PyTuple_Resize`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/755d4ef8243050e5ff973524633caebd0ce03af9/Objects/tupleobject.c#L938):

```
if (oldsize == 0) {
    /* Empty tuples are often shared, so we should never
       resize them in-place even if we do own the only
       (current) reference */
    Py_DECREF(v);
    *pv = PyTuple_New(newsize);
    return *pv == NULL ? -1 : 0;
}
```

However, my point is that one has to make sure, that there are no other references before calling `_PyTuple_Resize`.

Now, even if using `_PyTuple_Resize` for a tuple which is unknown to other parts of program:

```py
b = c_ssize_t(2)
A=py_object(("no one knows me",))
pythonapi._PyTuple_Resize(byref(A), b) # returns 0 - means everything ok
```

We get an object which is in an inconsistent state:

```py
print(A)
# py_object(('no one knows me', <NULL>))
```

The problem is the `NULL`-pointer as second element: now many of operations (like `print(A.value)`) with `A.value` will segfault or lead to other problems.

So now, one needs to use [`PyTuple_SetItem`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_SetItem) (it handles the `NULL` elements correctly and doesn't try to decrease reference of a NULL-pointer) to set `NULL`-elements  in the tuple before anything can be done with `A.value`. Btw. usually one would use `PyTuple_SET_ITEM` for newly created tuple/elements, but it is [a define](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/54ba556c6c7d8fd5504dc142c2e773890c55a774/Include/cpython/tupleobject.h#L30) and thus not part of `pythonapi`.

As `PyTuple_SetItem` steals a reference, so we need to take care of it as well:

```py
B=py_object(666)
pythonapi.Py_IncRef(B)
pythonapi.PyTuple_SetItem(A,1,B)
print(A.value)
# ('no one knows me', 666)
```

---

For small tuples `_PyTuple_Resize` will always (for 64bit-builds) create a new tuple-object and not reuse the old one, because adding an element means adding 8 bytes to the memory footprint (at least for 64bit-builds) and pymalloc returns 8byte-aligned pointers, thus differently to [adding chars to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54006987/5769463), a new object will be needed:

```py
b = c_ssize_t(2)
A=py_object(("no one knows me",))
print(id(A.value))
# 2311126190344
pythonapi._PyTuple_Resize(byref(A), b)
print(id(A.value))
# 2311143455304
```

We see the different ids!

However, for tuple-objects with memory-footprint larger than 512 bytes the memory is managed by the underlying c-runtime memory allocator and and thus resizing of the pointer is possible:

```py
b = c_ssize_t(1002)
A=py_object(("no one knows me",)*1000)
print(id(A.value))
# 2350988176984
pythonapi._PyTuple_Resize(byref(A), b)
print(id(A.value))
# 2350988176984
```

Now, the old object is extended - and the id is kept!

Comment: *sys.getrefcount* returned that value because *()* is a singleton (like many others: *None*, *True*, *-1*, *0*, *1*, *2,*, ...)

Comment: There's an alternative to create an arbitrary not empty tuple: https://pastebin.com/esDZbCJh Then you can resize it, and it will contains only `NULL`s, to be filled with `PyTuple_SetItem` (**not** `PyTuple_SET_ITEM`)

Comment: @MarcoSulla You are right, I wrongly assumed that `PyTuple_SetItem` could not handle `NULL`s (usually one would use `PyTuple_SET_ITEM` to assign newly created elements). However using `PyTuple_New` is not the same as `_PyTuple_Resize`, but did you wanted to create a new tuple and not to resize an existing?

Comment: Yes, I want to create it empty, resize it and populate it. Shortly, I want to see if doing something like this is more fast that populate a list and convert it to a tuple. Probably I have to tune the size of resizing... I have to do some tests and check the CPython code and see how `_PyTuple_Resize` is used.

Comment: @MarcoSulla list overallocates, so appending an element has average cost of O(1). The problem of tuples: there is no difference between the size of a tuple and the capacity of a tuple (so we can increase the size without the need of reallocation). Thus you have to reallocate for every append and thus you must depend on the ability of the c-runtime memory manager to reallocate memory without moving data too often, but due to memory fragmentation the running time of appending an element can become `O(n)` on average. It is tricky because the problem could occur only after some hours of running.

Comment: Can't I overallocate also the tuple?

Comment: @MarcoSulla At least not out of the box: list-object has information about the capacity of the underlying C-array https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/listobject.h#L39, tuple has not: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/cpython/tupleobject.h#L9

Comment: I chacked `PySequence_Tuple` in `abstract.c`, the equivalent of `tuple(iterable)`. It seems very simple. It starts with an empty tuple of size n=10, then every time you need more space, n is augmented by 10 and by a 25%. It's a more aggressive strategy than lists. I'll try it and see the benchs.